# "Бюджет свободный" ИЛИ "Бюджет: свободный?"

Tags: двоеточие

Нужно ли ставить двоеточие после слова "бюджет", если он - свободный.
Аналогичная ситуация:
"Цена договорная" или "Цена: договорная"?

Comment: Цена - договорная. - ну так еще можно, но двоеточие зачем? Цена договорная, свободный бюджет...